# PDO PostgreSQL "could not find driver" error with MAMP on Windows

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, mamp

I'm trying to connect to a PostgreSQL via a PHP script which runs on MAMP local server for Windows:

```
$db = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=dbName", "user", "password");
```

This throws an error "could not find driver"

So I looked for ";extension=pdo_pgsql" and ";extension=pgsql" in the php.ini file, and removed the ";". Saved and restarted the MAMP's local server.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Unfortunately, PDO_PGSQL still doesn't appear to be loading

[image]

I don't have any of these problems on the MacOS version of MAMP. Am I missing some extra steps?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem

 `export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/10/bin:$PATH` worked for me